# Loop through visible worksheets and refresh all hidden Pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dedicated computer and TV screen they are both only for the purpose of showing sales figures for the entire business to see.

I have a spreadsheet with 3 visible worksheets "Sales for the day", "Sales for the month" and "Sales for the year". These worksheets are linked to hidden pivot tables in the same workbook.

Can someone kindly design a Macro that loops through the worksheets after 30 second intervals. Now the tricky part is that the pivot tables in the workbook should refresh after every 30 minutes.

The refreshing should make a short break in the changing of worksheets loop, but after the refreshing is done the loop should continue back to the way it was.

Please your assistance will be highly appreciated and I will send you a picture of how your master piece will look.

The loop code I have is below...

```
Sub Test()
  Dim i As Long, t As Single

  On Error GoTo exit_
  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
  Do
    i = i + 1
    If i > 3 Then i = 1
    If i = 1 Then
    Sheets("Sales for the day").Select
    ElseIf i = 1 Then
    Sheets("Sales for yesterday").Select
    ElseIf i = 2 Then
    Sheets("Sales for the month").Select
    ElseIf i = 3 Then
    Sheets("Sales for the year").Select
    End If
    t = Timer + 1
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)
    If Timer < t Then Exit Do
  Loop
exit_:

End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't a "write my code for me" service, it's a Q&A site. If you have some code that you've already tried and you're stuck then feel free to show us what you've got and we can help fix it. But no research effort = no answers.

Comment: Look at `Application.OnTime` method - this allows you to schedule code to run at set times/intervals

Comment: does your code produce an error?

Comment: This is the code that i used and it is working...

Comment: **Sub Loop_Macro()**

**Worksheets("Sales for the day").Activate**

**Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))**

**Worksheets("Sales for the month").Activate**

**Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))**

**Worksheets("Sales for the year").Activate**

**Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))**

**ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll**

**Loop_Macro**

**End Sub**